# Change startEditable value of individual event after it's been rendered

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I want to toggle an event's `startEditable` value when it's clicked.
It's true by default for every event.

I've tried doing it by manually assigning the property value but it's not working:

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  ...,
  editable: true,
  eventClick: function(info){
          info.event.startEditable = false;
        },
  ...
}
```

Since changing the style is possible like this:

```
eventClick: function(info){
          info.el.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
        }
```

Does that mean it's not possible to modify an event object after it's already been rendered?

If not, how can I make an event non-editable post-render?

Edit: here's a [CodePen with an example of the issue](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gVrYXN).

Comment: Why do you want to change the editable property when it's clicked? Not sure I understand the use case. Surely whether something is editable can be defined when the event is first rendered?

Comment: It's for locking an event so you don't accidentally move it while fiddling with other events near it.
Anyway, it was a simple event.setProp('startEditable', bool). I had misread the docs and thought this wasn't possible, so I didn't even try it. But that was it! :(

Answer (score 1):

What I needed is the setProp method:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
        info.event.setProp('startEditable', Boolean);
      }
```

I had misread the docs and thought it wasn't possible this way, but the opposite was true.

Especifically for toggling:

```
eventClick: function(info) {
        info.event.setProp('startEditable', !info.event.startEditable);
      }
```